# eclipse container path cannot be null

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

i am starting developing appium tests. i installed eclipse, appium and NGTest library and some other stuff.
When trying to run my tests (Device is connected via PDANet, Appium server is running) i get the error about container path.

But i found this file .classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/commons-exec-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/cssparser-0.9.22.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/gson-2.8.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/guava-21.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/htmlunit-2.26.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/htmlunit-core-js-2.26.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/htmlunit-driver-2.26.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/httpclient-4.5.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/httpcore-4.4.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/httpmime-4.5.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/jetty-io-9.4.1.v20170120.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/jetty-util-9.4.1.v20170120.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/neko-htmlunit-2.25.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/sac-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/websocket-api-9.4.3.v20170317.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/websocket-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/websocket-common-9.4.3.v20170317.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/zachmste/Downloads/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

So what did i miss? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that TestNG and the Android framework are set up properly for the project? Should you actually have that second org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER value?

Comment: i am not sure. how can i validate that TestNG and Android is set up correct?
Shall i remove the JRE_Container value?

Comment: Yes. Remove it.

Comment: I did, but same result. Even restart did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by re-cloning the project and do a checkout of the develop branch.
Now i can start my application.